# Proof that this operator is linear and bounded, find operator norm

Tags: functional-analysis

A:C[-1,1] to C[0,1]

[image]

That means x(0) here?

Comment: Presumably $x\colon [-1,1]\to [0,1]$ is a given a given continuous function and as such $x(0)$ is what it is.

Comment: The resulting operator norm depends on which norms you are using for $C[-1,1]$ and $C[0,1]$.  So, which are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Linearity: $A [ \alpha x(t) + \beta y(t) ] = t^2 [\alpha x + \beta y](0) = t^2 (\alpha x(0)) + t^2 (\beta y(0)) = \alpha  t^2 x(0) + \beta t^2  y(0) = \alpha A x(t) + \beta y(t)$.

Operator norm: $||A x(t)|| = ||t^2 x(0)|| = ||t^2|| |x(0)| \leq (1) |x(0)| = |x(0)| <= ||x(t)||$ since $t^2 \leq 1$. Choosing $x(t) = 1$ shows this equality is met, thus the operator norm is indeed $1$. (The norm is the sup norm).